# When using iAds in iPhone and iPad SDK, do we have to provide the ads?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4, iad

I am making an iPhone and iPad app, which has a requirement for iAds. I am a beginner into using iAds into my apps.

So I wanted to know whether we have to provide the iAds for our app while submitting to Apple's iTunes store or will it be randomly assigned by Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need provide ad, it is chosen by apple service.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am not clear about wat u said. Do you mean that We have to put ad Banner view and apple will select ads for that?

Comment: Yes, automatically, nothing you need to worry about.